# Proof of Identity to Zero of the Sum of a Product of Binomial Coefficients & Pochhammer Numbers

Tags: binomial-coefficients, pochhammer-symbol

It's well-know that the sum across an entire row of binomial coefficients (of degree, say, $n$) with alternating signs attached is 0; and it can easily be proven by demonstrating that it is the binomial expansion of $(1-1)^n$. What is less obvious is that if you take the same series & multiply the terms in it by consecutive Pochhammer numbers of degree $n-1$, but from ***anywhere*** along that series, the sum is still zero! To put it formally $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k(m+k)_{n-1}}{k!(n-k)!}=0 ,$$  $∀m\geq n-1$, it not mattering that the $n!$ is omitted in the denominator, as only the relative size of the terms matters, the sum being putatively 0. That this is so follows from a tracing of the combinatorial consequence on the terms in the series expansion about 1 of the logarithm of the property of the logarithm, that the logarithm of a product = the sum of the logarithms; so if we have a proof through some other route (which we do) that the property & the series imply each other, then we effectively *already have* a proof of the theorem adduced as the grounds of this post ... but an ***exceedingly*** roundabout proof! There must be a more elementary proof than that ... but I can't figure it out. I have a very vague recollection of seeing one when reading elementary stuff on binomial coefficients a long time ago; but I'm not *absolutely certain* I did - it might have been a proof of some other theorem.

It did occur to me that one route through which it might be proven that of *recasting* the $n$th row (the very top one with $1$ only in it being the zeroth) of the binomial coefficient triangle as being the series $$1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\prod_{l=0}^k\frac{l-k}{l+1} ,$$ whence the one queried in this post being recast as  $$1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\prod_{l=0}^k\frac{(l-k)(l+m+n)}{(l+1)(l+m+1)} ∀m∊ℕ_0$$ the absolute value mattering not atall, as it is only the *relative* value of the terms that matters, the sum being putatively zero.

I don't know that this *is* the best way to the proof, but it did occur to me it might be viable. I wonder whether anyone would show a proof or a clue to one, whether by this means or otherwise.

There *might possibly* be a clue in the fact that the lastmentioned series *could just as well* be $$1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\prod_{l=0}^k\frac{(l-k)(l+m+1)}{(l+1)(l+m+n)} ∀m∊ℕ_0$$ as because the binomial coefficients are symmetrical from front to back, it matters not in which direction the series of Pochhammer numbers is traversed.

Comment: What exactly is the identity you're trying to prove?

Comment: The sum of __alternating__ binomial coefficients (of degree say, n) is 0 - we know _that_, & it's easy to prove. But if you take a subsequence of consecutive Pochhammer numbers of degree n-1 (products of n-1 consecutive integers ... or _polyhedral_ numbers of degree n-1, if you prefer, they're just Pochhammer numbers ÷by (n-1)!) and multiply each (alernating) binomial coefficient by each Pochhammer number in order, traversing each sequence one at a time, the sum is still zero. It''ll no doubt transpire to be  elementary binomial coefficient stuff!

Comment: If you have a term for $l=k$ and one of the factors in the numerator is $l-k$, the product will be $0$.  I don't think that's what you mean.

Comment: I've clarified what theorem I mean in the body of the question. ¶ Right yes! that going to zero when l=k, that just makes the sequence 0 thereafter ... as it ought to, as it's the binomial coefficients. Those expressions with the sum & product signs in are just a _distillaton_ of the formula with the factorials & Pochammer symbols in - going to the next pochhamner number is equivalent to dividing by the _smallest_ factor in the _present_ one & multiplying by the _largest_ in the _next_ one ... or multipltying by 1>than the largest in the present one.

Comment: It's really frustrating actually, coz I can easily verify it with a spreadsheet, and I know it's not _particularly_ advanced binomial-coefficient theory (in fact it's _extremely_ elementary compared to how stratospheric some of that stuff gets!), but I just can't nail how to actually _do_ it. In standard texts it might be a bit _disguised_ relative to my formulation of it (in terms of Pochamner numbers) - you might well find it done purely in terms of binomial coefficients - but essentially the same theorem.

Comment: Note that [Wolfram](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pochhammer.html) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) have different definitions of the Pochammer Symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{1}{k!(n-k)!} (m+k)^\underline{n-1}$$

we get

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-k)!}
{m+k\choose n-1}
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k}
{m+k\choose n-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k}
[z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{m+k}
\\ = [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{m}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} (1+z)^k
\\ = [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{m}
\frac{1}{n} (1-(1+z))^n
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n}{n} [z^{n-1}] z^n (1+z)^{m}
= 0.$$

Here we have  used the fact that  $z^n (1+z)^{m} = z^n  + \cdots$ note
however that we are extracting the coefficient on $[z^{n-1}].$ Careful
inspection reveals  that this  will go  through for  $n\ge 1$  and all
integer $m$  including negative. This  is because $(1+z)^m$  is entire
when $m\ge  0$ and  the only  pole of  $(1+z)^m$ when  $m\lt 0$  is at
$z=-1.$

Observe  that  this  is  the combinatorial  interpretation  of  the
Pochhammer symbol as the falling factorial  as opposed to the one from
special     functions.      These     two    are     documented     at
[MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html).   The
proof for the alternate notation is left to the reader.

Comment: That is _slick_ that is! I'll need to _cast it in my mind_ (as the King James Bible is very fond of saying!) to get it properly 'of a piece'. (Nearly said 'integrated' ... but that might have been confusing on a mathematics thread!) Sort of a _generating function_ method. Like I said, I had _effectively_ proven it by showing that it's a necessary condition for the _logarithm_ to have its _property_ given its Taylor series ... which is effectively another _absurdly complicated_ quasi generator-function method ... but there _just had to be_ something simpler! Thankyou for that.

Answer (score 1):

The [forward Finite Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) of a function $f(x)$ is defined as
$$
\Delta \,f(x) = f(x + 1) - f(x)
$$
and its iteration as
$$
\Delta ^{\,n} \,f(x) = \Delta \left( {\,\Delta ^{\,n - 1} \,f(x)} \right)
  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{n - k} \left( \matrix{ n \cr  k \cr}  \right)\;f(x + k)} 
$$

It is a [known fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Newton%27s_series) that if $f(x)=p_q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $q$ then, similarly to derivatives, 
$$
\Delta ^{\,n} \,p_{\,q} (x) = 0\quad \left| {\;q < n} \right.
$$

So the case you propose is just
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \;} {{\left( {x + k} \right)_{\,n - 1} } \over {k!\left( {n - k} \right)!}}
 = \left( { - 1} \right)^n n!\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{n - k} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\;(x + k)_{n - 1} } _\,  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^n n!\Delta ^{\,n} \,x^{\,\overline {\,n - 1\,} }
  = \left( { - 1} \right)^n n!\Delta ^{\,n} \prod\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,n - 2} {\left( {x + j} \right)} \, = 0 \cr} 
$$
with x integer, real or complex.

Comment: And that implies that the theorem infact holds for the degree of the Pochhammer numbers being _less_ than n-1 also - that 1 & n-1 are not special cases. _And_ ... I know you have used _x_ as a convenience ... or are you? ... no, you're showing me that it's true also for general real values of x _as well as_ naturals! Thankyou for that - it's a very thorough answer - it's _well_ dissipated the fog!

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey: glad to have helped and yes,  $x$ can be even .. **complex** .. and even a **matrix**.  The Delta (forward and backward) formula is quite basic to discrete maths: I do suggest you to get well acquainted with it. So.. you can discover by yourself what you get when taking the nth-Delta of a degree-n polynomial

Comment: It is something I've looked-at before ... but not enough really - never _is_ quite enough! - and I've even _used_ it often enough for computing derivatives numerically, & similar things. But I get too easily _putoff_ sonetimes by the more rarified theory of things like that. Altough what you've just shown me is _maturing & settling_ in my mind very nicely now.

Comment: I'm not too keen on this business of only being able to vote for one answer though ... so I'm just leaving that. I'll stick to saying what I think through comments. And that applies generally. ¶ Yes - I've seen how you can have e^∆, & stuff like that.